# XAMPP не позволяет загрузить нужную страницу

Tags: apache, xampp

При вводе localhost в адресную строку, выводит страницу другого проекта. Причем, в файлах конфигурации Apache: `httpd.conf`, `httpd-xampp.conf` не прописано подобного пути проекта, который запускается. VirtualHosts почему-то не работают вовсе. Как можно запустить нужный проект?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы помочь Вашему горю нужно видеть конфигурацию Вашего apache.

Очевидно, что Ваши VirtualHosts настроены не совсем корректно, а точнее `_default_:*` скорее всего отсутствует, или Вы его пропустили.

Вам нужно определить как минимум 2 виртуальных хоста во всей конфигурации:

1. Хост `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` — который будет обрабатывать всё, что не попало под другие хосты
2. Хост `<VirtualHost *:80>` — в котором **будет указан** `ServerName` с действующим именем сервера.

О том, что я написал можно прочитать в [официальной документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default).

Comment: Спасибо) Мне это помогло.
Убрал оттуда всё лишнее и добавил Хост <VirtualHost _default_:80> - заработало!

Comment: Если мой ответ являлся правильным, пожалуйста, отметьте его, чтобы остальные были уверены в решении